# d3js donut chart - highlight first data

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

In my project i have a requirement to create a donut chart,so i am using d3js.
On page load after creating the chart, the first value of the chart should be highlighted and the value should displayed in the center

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title> D3 Js Example </title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="main.css" />
</head>
<body>

    <div id="my_dataviz"></div>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.9.7/d3.min.js" ></script>
    <script>
var width = 450
    height = 450
    margin = 40

var radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2 - margin

var svg = d3.select("#my_dataviz")
  .append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");

var data = {a: 9, b: 20, c:30, d:8, e:12}

var color = d3.scaleOrdinal()
  .domain(data)
  .range(["#98abc5", "#8a89a6", "#7b6888", "#6b486b", "#a05d56"])

var pie = d3.pie()
  .value(function(d) {return d.value; })
var data_ready = pie(d3.entries(data))

  
svg
  .selectAll('whatever')
  .data(data_ready)
  .enter()
  .append('path')
  .attr('d', d3.arc()
    .innerRadius(100)         
    .outerRadius(radius)
  )
  .attr('fill', function(d){ return(color(d.data.key)) })
  .attr("stroke", "black")
  .style("stroke-width", "2px")
  .style("opacity", 0.7)
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: well in pure d3, thats quite some work i believe, you can tho try to use d3pie(a d3 plugin, they even have a generator), that alone will take care of the hover effect, and eveyrthing labels and titles related, for the shadow the easy way is to apply a drop-shadow to the svg, hope it give you some direction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the arc shape functions that generate the content for the `d` attributes of each of the `path` elements that make up the donut segments.

So, one approach is to use a different arc shape generator to draw the first segment (with different inner and outer radius settings) than is used to draw the other segments. You can use the second argument of the functions given to the `attr()` methods, which is the index of your data (see the example).

You can do the same for the colour. For the fill attribute of the first segment, specify your specific highlight colour, else use your colour scale to generate it:

```
var normalArc = d3.arc().innerRadius(100).outerRadius(185);
var biggerArc = d3.arc().innerRadius(85).outerRadius(200);

svg
  .selectAll('whatever')
  .data(data_ready)
  .enter()
  .append('path')
  .attr('d', function(d, index) {
    // If this is the first segment make it a wider arc
    if(index === 0) {
      return biggerArc(d);
    } else {
      return normalArc(d);
    }
  })
  .attr('fill', function(d, index){ 
    // If this is the first segment, highlight it.
    if(index === 0) {
      return '#ff1dce';
    } else {
      return(color(d.data.key))
    }
  })
  .attr("stroke", "black")
  .style("stroke-width", "2px")
  .style("opacity", 0.7);
```